# EF 6.0 with TPH and TPC inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using code first EF 6.1 and i ran to the following situation

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
     public int BaseId { get; set;}
     public int Remark { get; set;}
}

public class FirstDerivedClass : BaseClass
{

}

public class SecondDerivedClass : BaseClass
{
      public int NumberOfDays { get; set;}
}

public class DatabaseContext:DbContext
{
     public DbSet<BaseClass> Data { get; set;}
}
```

and the generated tables in data base in only one table Data with additional column Discriminator and also the column NumberOfDays is there and this was expected since it is TPH.

now i am trying to add another table **SecondDerivedClass** with only Id ( PK,FK) and property **NumberOfDay** so SecondDerivedClass will be TPC

so i tried the following

```
public class DatabaseContext:DbContext
{
     public DbSet<BaseClass> Data { get; set;}
     public DbSet<SecondDerivedClass> DerivedData { get; set;}

}
```

and when i try to add data to DerivedData, the discriminator field will not get filled by the name of the class **SecondDerivedClass** , how to oblige the EF to fill this field?

is there any idea that will help me?

Comment: you don't need the discriminator field when you are using the TPC inheritance

Comment: And you probably shouldn't mix TPC and TPH with the same base class.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thank you for the tip, can i extend my question to solve another problem i am facing which is multilevel inheritance?

Comment: i was trying to apply normalization to my code to avoid repeating the field Remark inside SecondDerivedClass and to get normalized tables

Comment: There are some guidelines: ask 1 question per question, don't ask followups in comments. The posted sample is too small and artificial to give good advice. Present your case again, business classes with the main details, and ask how to model them.